# SharePoint - Set nested term for a user profile property using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

I'm setting some user profile properties using CSOM, specifically some properties backed by term sets. The only way to do this (that I know of) are the `SetSingleValueProfileProperty` and `SetMultiValuedProfileProperty` methods of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` object. These work fine to set the property values when using simple term sets, but not as well if the term set has a hierarchical structure.

In my specific example we're setting a user's location, and the term set has a hierarchical structure of

> Country -> City

So every City is a child of a Country. Assuming the terms already exist in the term set you can simply pass in the name of a City and it will find that nested term and use it, no problem. But consider the case when we have both Paris, France and Paris, USA in the term set. Passing in the string "Paris" will set the property to the first Paris it finds (Paris, France), but how can I set the value to be Paris, USA instead?

I tried passing in *USA:Paris*, which resulted in a new term named that. I also tried passing in *Paris|GUID_OF_TERM* but that fails saying | is an illegal character.

Does anyone have a way to specify a specific nested term when setting a profile property using CSOM?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to add an extra label to the term. So if you have Paris 2 times just add a label like for example USA_Paris. 
[image: Extra Label]

Now you can set the different terms in the user profile using these other labels in the

```
setSingleValueProfileProperty
```

and

```
setMultiValuedProfileProperty
```